# redirect subdomain without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I got apache2 with mod_rewrite and I also have access to .htaccess of the site.

I want the URL `profile.domain.com/username` to redirect to `www.domain.com/profiles/php?user=username` but keep the URL to be `profile.domain.com/username`. I have already got a wildcard setup to catch all subdomains. I am trying to use:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^profile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.+)$          http://www.domain.com/profiles/php?user=%1 [R=301,L]
```

But it changed the URL to `http://www.domain.com/profiles/php?user=` and never catched the username. Also, I don't want it to change the URL I want it to stay `profile.domain.com/username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is almost correct. `%1` is replaced by the first capture group in the last `RewriteCond`. Since there is no first capture group, it is replaced by.... nothing. You want to use `$1` instead. That is replaced by the first capture group in the `RewriteRule`.

The second mistake you make is making it an external redirect with the `R`-flag. Remove that flag, and remove the domain-name, and it is treated as an internal rewrite. Make sure you empty the cache of your browser, because it will 'remember' the external redirect you made, and not use the new rewriterules you have.

You'll end up with:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^profile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.+)$          /profiles/php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I had something simmilar to this without using a different subdomain but I get `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Figured it out, just had to add an extra RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  ![phpfilename]$